# Creating object from ProductionWorker1 class and using setters and getters

Tags: java, inheritance, getter-setter

I need to be able to get keyboard input and passing it to the object created from the ProductionWorker1 class. The ProductionWorker1 class extends the Employee1 class to get the name, number, and date(hired). The ProductionWorker1 class has a default constructor with the shift and pay. The Employee1 constructor has the name, number and date. If anyone can help i'd really appreciate it.

```
public class Employee1 
{
  public Employee1(String name)
  {
     System.out.println("name: " + name);
  }
    public void setName(String name)
    {
      name = name;
    }
    public String getName(String name)
    {
      return name;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class ProductionWorker1 extends Employee1
{

  public ProductionWorker1(int shift, double pay)
  {
     super("");
     System.out.println("shift: " + shift);
     System.out.println("pay: " + pay);

  }
  public void setShift(int shift)
  {
    shift = shift;
  }
  public int getShift(int shift)
  {
    return shift;
  }

}
```

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main 
{
  public static void main(String[] s)
   {
     String name;
     String shift;
     String pay;
     Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("enter name");
     name = keyboard.nextLine();
     System.out.println("enter shift time");
     shift = keyboard.nextLine();
     System.out.println("enter pay");
     pay = keyboard.nextLine();

     ProductionWorker1 obj = new ProductionWorker1(obj.getName());
  }
}
```

Comment: ??? check out the last line of main. You are setting a class to a new instance and sending the constructor that Object's name before setting the object. Don't you mean to pass it the String name?

Comment: @older coder I changes the variable shift and pay to int and double then passed int and double to the obj:
int shift;
double pay;
ProductionWorker1 obj = new ProductionWorker1(int, shift);
this worked. do you know how to use the setters and getters from the other classes? since I'm just using the variable in Main?

Comment: You say the `Employee1` constructor takes a name, number and date, but it only takes the name. Also, your classes don't have any attributes.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you started. Sorry, but I was side-tracked. In main, find out how to convert a string into an int. Same with pay. It would be better to simply scan them in as their type.

```
 /**
  * You have setters and getters, but you don't have any class variables to set/get
  * @author me
  *
  */

  public class Employee1 {
  // You don't have any class variables.
  // I added this one.
        String name;

        public Employee1(String name)  {
              // I added this line to set the class variable name to parameter name
              setName(name);
              System.out.println("In Constructor Employee1(String) name: " + name);
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
        // I changed this to set the class name to the parameter name
              this.name = name;
        }

        /**
         * IF You are getting the class variable, you don't need to pass a variable to get it.
         * @return
         */
         public String getName() {
              return name;
        }
  }


public class ProductionWorker1 extends Employee1 {

// Since ProductionWorker1 extends Employee, it will
// have a name variable. Now add shift and pay for ProductionWorker1
int shift = 0;
double pay = 0.0;

/**
 * Constructor with NO NAME!!!
 * @param shift
 * @param pay
 */
public ProductionWorker1(int shift, double pay)  {
    super("");  // initializes Employee1 and sets name to empty string
    setShift(shift);
    setPay(pay);
    System.out.println("In Constructor ProductionWorker1(int,double)shift: " + shift);
    System.out.println("pay: " + pay);

}

/**
* I added this Constructor to get the name down to Employee1
* @param name
* @param shift
* @param pay
*/
public ProductionWorker1(String name, int shift, double pay) {
    super(name);    // initializes Employee1 and sets name to ProductionWorker's name
    setShift(shift);
    setPay(pay);
    System.out.println("In Constructor ProductionWorker1(String int,double)shift: " + shift);
    System.out.println("pay: " + pay);
}

public double getPay() {
   return pay;
}
public void setPay(double pay) {
    this.pay = pay;
}

public void setShift(int shift) {
    this.shift = shift;
}

public int getShift() {
    return shift;
}

}



public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
     String name;
     String shift;
     String pay;
     Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("enter name");
     name = keyboard.nextLine();
     System.out.println("enter shift time");
     shift = keyboard.nextLine();
     System.out.println("enter pay");
     pay = keyboard.nextLine();

     // !!! You need to create an int from a string OR you could scan it in
     // as an integer. For now, I'm using a temp int.
     int tempShift = 5;
     // same with pay
     double tempPay = 12.56;

     ProductionWorker1 obj = new ProductionWorker1(name, tempShift, tempPay);
     // obj dude got a raise
     obj.setPay(24.75);

}
```